# testing interactive python programs

Tags: python, testing

I would like to know which testing tools for python support the testing of interactive programs. For example, I have an application launched by:

```
$ python dummy_program.py 

>> Hi whats your name? Joseph
```

I would like to instrument `Joseph` so I can emulate that interactive behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

If you are testing an interactive program, consider using [expect](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm). It's designed specifically for interacting with console programs (though, more for automating tasks rather than testing).

If you don't like the language expect is based on (tcl) you can try [pexpect](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pexpect/) which also makes it easy to interact with a console program.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably dependency injection, so that what you'd ordinarily pick up from sys.stdin (for example) is actually an object passed in. So you might do something like this:

```
import sys

def myapp(stdin, stdout):
    print >> stdout, "Hi, what's your name?"
    name = stdin.readline()
    print >> stdout "Hi,", name

# This might be in a separate test module
def test_myapp():
    mock_stdin = [create mock object that has .readline() method]
    mock_stdout = [create mock object that has .write() method]
    myapp(mock_stdin, mock_stdout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myapp(sys.stdin, sys.stdout)
```

Fortunately, Python makes this pretty easy. Here's a more detailed link for an example of mocking stdin: http://konryd.blogspot.com/2010/05/mockity-mock-mock-some-love-for-mock.html

Comment: Indeed, dependency injection is the way to go. Although, if for some strange reason he can't change the code, he could directly change `stdin` and `stdout` with `sys.stdin = mock_stdin` and `sys.stdout = mock_stdout`. If he needed the originals during the test, he could use `sys.__stdin__` and `sys.__stdout__`, which keep the original values.

Answer (score 0):

A good example might be the file [test_embed.py](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/terminal/tests/test_embed.py) of the IPython package.

There two different approaches are used:

**subprocess**

```
import subprocess
# ...
subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=env, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate(_exit_cmd_string)
```

**pexpect** (as already mentioned by [Brian Oakley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley)

```
import pexpect
# ...
child = pexpect.spawn(sys.executable, ['-m', 'IPython', '--colors=nocolor'],
                          env=env)
# ...
child.sendline("some_command")
child.expect(ipy_prompt)
```