# How can I simulate input to stdin for pyunit?

Tags: python, linux, python-unittest

I'm trying to test a function that takes input from `stdin`, which I'm currently testing with something like this:

```
cat /usr/share/dict/words | ./spellchecker.py
```

In the name of test automation, is there any way that `pyunit` can fake input to `raw_input()`?

Comment: You might like to try structuring your app for dependency injection, as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716630/testing-interactive-python-programs/4716735#4716735) to a similar question.

Comment: http://uuoc.com/ ;-) (Should be `./spellchecker.py < /usr/share/dict/words`)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The short answer is to [monkey patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) `raw_input()`.

There are some good examples in the answer to [How to display the redirected stdin in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812333/how-to-display-the-redirected-stdin-in-python)

Here is a simple, trivial example using a `lambda` that throws away the prompt and returns what we want.

### System Under Test

```
cat ./name_getter.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

class NameGetter(object):

    def get_name(self):
        self.name = raw_input('What is your name? ')

    def greet(self):
        print 'Hello, ', self.name, '!'

    def run(self):
        self.get_name()
        self.greet()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ng = NameGetter()
    ng.run()

$ echo Derek | ./name_getter.py 
What is your name? Hello,  Derek !
```

### Test case:

```
$ cat ./t_name_getter.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import unittest
import name_getter

class TestNameGetter(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_get_alice(self):
        name_getter.raw_input = lambda _: 'Alice'
        ng = name_getter.NameGetter()
        ng.get_name()
        self.assertEquals(ng.name, 'Alice')

    def test_get_bob(self):
        name_getter.raw_input = lambda _: 'Bob'
        ng = name_getter.NameGetter()
        ng.get_name()
        self.assertEquals(ng.name, 'Bob')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

$ ./t_name_getter.py -v
test_get_alice (__main__.TestNameGetter) ... ok
test_get_bob (__main__.TestNameGetter) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Comment: Sorry, where is `name_getter.raw_input` defined on `NameGetter`?

Comment: @Alper It isn't. The tests monkey-patch [the built-in function `raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) for the `name_getter` module.

Answer (score 19):

#### Update -- using unittest.mock.patch

Since python 3.3 there is new submodule for `unittest` called mock that does exactly what you need to do. For those using python 2.6 or above there is a backport of `mock` found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock).

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

import module_under_test


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # raw_input is untouched before test
        assert module_under_test.raw_input is __builtins__.raw_input

    def test_using_with(self):
        input_data = "123"
        expected = int(input_data)

        with patch.object(module_under_test, "raw_input", create=True, 
                return_value=expected):
            # create=True is needed as raw_input is not in the globals of 
            # module_under_test, but actually found in __builtins__ .
            actual = module_under_test.function()

        self.assertEqual(expected, actual)

    @patch.object(module_under_test, "raw_input", create=True)
    def test_using_decorator(self, raw_input):
        raw_input.return_value = input_data = "123"
        expected = int(input_data)

        actual = module_under_test.function()

        self.assertEqual(expected, actual)

    def tearDown(self):
        # raw input is restored after test
        assert module_under_test.raw_input is __builtins__.raw_input

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
# where module_under_test.function is:
def function():
    return int(raw_input("prompt> "))
```

#### Previous answer -- replacing sys.stdin

I think the sys module might be what you're looking for.

You can do something like

```
import sys

# save actual stdin in case we need it again later
stdin = sys.stdin

sys.stdin = open('simulatedInput.txt','r') 
# or whatever else you want to provide the input eg. StringIO
```

raw_input will now read from simulatedInput.txt whenever it is called. If the contents of simulatedInput was

```
hello
bob
```

then the first call to raw_input would return "hello", the second "bob" and third would throw an EOFError as there was no more text to read.

Comment: Unit tests should not access the filesystem.

Comment: @Johnsyweb Why not? Mind to elaborate and enlighten me? How do I test filemanipulation functions then, and would using `stringIO` instead of a real file be better and if so how? (Besides beeing faster than disk IO, but the data comes from the disk sooner or later anyway and taht way yuo could seperate test **data** from test **code**.

Comment: @ted: It's a good point you make about the separation of code from data, but your question in difficult to answer generically (particular in the comments of somebody else's answer. I recommend asking this as a new question.

Comment: `sys.stdin` and the stream returned by `open()` aren't exactly the same. For example, if your code does `stream.tell()`, then it will work in this test but not with the real `sys.stdin`.

Comment: I think this should be updated since `raw_input` is now gone form the python API and is replaced by `input`

Answer (score 4):

You didn't describe what sort of code is in `spellchecker.py`, which gives me freedom to speculate.

Suppose it's something like this:

```
import sys

def check_stdin():
  # some code that uses sys.stdin
```

To improve testability of `check_stdin` function, I propose to refactor it like so:

```
def check_stdin():
  return check(sys.stdin)

def check(input_stream):
  # same as original code, but instead of
  # sys.stdin it is written it terms of input_stream.
```

Now most of your logic is in `check` function, and you can hand-craft whatever input you can imagine in order to test it properly, without any need to deal with `stdin`.

My 2 cents.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `sys.stdin` with an instance of `StringIO`, and load the `StringIO` instance with the data you want returned via `sys.stdin`.  Also, `sys.__stdin__` contains the original `sys.stdin` object, so restoring `sys.stdin` after your test is as simple as `sys.stdin = sys.__stdin__`.

[Fudge](http://farmdev.com/projects/fudge/) is a great python mock module, with convenient decorators for doing patching like this for you, with automatic cleanup.  You should check it out.

Comment: If you have to monkey patch `sys.stdin`, there is a high possibility you are trying to "unit test" too much. Regarding Fudge, also consider the benefits of [rolling your own mocks](http://blog.objectmentor.com/articles/2009/10/28/manual-mocking-resisting-the-invasion-of-dots-and-parentheses).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [mock module](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html) (written by Michael Foord), in order to mock **raw_input** function you can use syntax like:

```
@patch('src.main.raw_input', create=True, new=MagicMock(return_value='y'))
def test_1(self):
    method_we_try_to_test();    # method or function that calls **raw_input**
```