# Give input to a python script from a shell?

Tags: python, shell

I'm trying to write a shell script that will run a python file that takes in some raw input. The python script is essentially along the lines of:

```
def main():
    name=raw_input("What's your name?")
    print "Hello, "+name
main()
```

I want the shell script to run the script and automatically feed input into it. I've seen plenty of ways to get shell input from what a python function returns, or how to run a shell from python with input, but not this way around. Basically, I just want something that does:

```
python hello.py
#  give the python script some input here
#  then continue on with the shell script.
```

Comment: `echo "read this!" | python hello.py` - what shell are we talking about anyway?

Comment: That looks like a UUOE (closely related to [UUOC](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html))

Comment: Also have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6271995/1025391) on automated testing and stdin input in Python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
python hello.py <<EOF
Matt
EOF
```

This is known as a [bash HERE document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).

Answer (score 4):

There's really no better way to give raw input than `sys.stdin`. It's cross platform too.

```
import sys
print "Hello {0}!".format(sys.stdin.read())
```

Then

```
echo "John" | python hello.py # From the shell
python hello.py < john.txt # From a file, maybe containing "John"
```

Comment: the second one is a useless use of cat ... `python hello.py < john.txt`

Comment: @mgilson Indeed...old habits die hard.

Comment: I still do that (pretty frequently).

Comment: I can't actually change the python files: I'm grading for an intro CS class, and they aren't teaching `sys`. I'm just trying to save myself time so I'm not giving manually input to 94 students' python scripts.