# How to unread a single char in Python?

Tags: python, io, token

I need to read a single char from stdin and then unread it so that the next time an input method is called, that char should be included in the result. In C++, cin.putback does this. What is the equivalent in Python?

Please note that I don't need to intermingle different input methods/functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I simulate input to stdin for pyunit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271947/how-can-i-simulate-input-to-stdin-for-pyunit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Python module called CIn which does exactly what I want. It is available on GitHub: https://github.com/abhishekkr200802/CIn

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3, [`sys.stdin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin) has a property called `buffer` that is an instance of [`io.BufferedReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedReader) and so has a [`peek`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedReader.peek) method.  This should allow you to do `sys.stdin.buffer.peek(1)[:1]`, which would let you look at the next character in standard input without reading (consuming) it.

Comment: Thanks. Anything similar for Python 2?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a simple analogue in Python.

Your best bet is probably to read the characters into an list in your program, and then later consume them from that list.

Comment: That will get dirty very soon unless I write some module doing it for me.