# Unit-test for python3 script using unittest

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have a little python3 script. Something like this

```
import sys


content = sys.stdin.read()

print(content)
```

I need to write a unit test for this using import unittest. I am trying to understand, how simulate stdin using unittest.

I found some articles [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271947/how-can-i-simulate-input-to-stdin-for-pyunit)

and [here](https://sophieau.com/article/python-in-out-err-mocking/), but I still couldn't deal with it, because after I run testing scripts, program expects me to give stdin.

Could you help me to rewrite this code (or write another) for testing my script

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

import module_under_test


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # raw_input is untouched before test
        assert module_under_test.raw_input is __builtins__.raw_input

    def test_using_with(self):
        input_data = "123"
        expected = int(input_data)

        with patch.object(module_under_test, "raw_input", create=True, 
                return_value=expected):
            # create=True is needed as raw_input is not in the globals of 
            # module_under_test, but actually found in __builtins__ .
            actual = module_under_test.function()

        self.assertEqual(expected, actual)

    @patch.object(module_under_test, "raw_input", create=True)
    def test_using_decorator(self, raw_input):
        raw_input.return_value = input_data = "123"
        expected = int(input_data)

        actual = module_under_test.function()

        self.assertEqual(expected, actual)

    def tearDown(self):
        # raw input is restored after test
        assert module_under_test.raw_input is __builtins__.raw_input

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: "something like" is a bad replacement for an actual [mcve], as it requires guessing the behaviour of an unspecified piece of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only need a single test method that uses [`patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch):

`script.py`:

```
import sys


def main():
  content = sys.stdin.read()
  print(content)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

`script_test.py`:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

import script


class ScriptTest(unittest.TestCase):

  @patch('sys.stdin.read')
  def test_content_reading(self, mock_stdin):
    mock_stdin.return_value = 'mocked data 123'
    with patch('builtins.print') as mock_print:
      script.main()
      mock_print.assert_called_once_with('mocked data 123')


if __name__ == '__main__':
  unittest.main()
```

**Example Usage:**

```
$ python -m unittest script_test.py
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.032s

OK
```

***[NB.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota_bene)** When using `sys.stdin.read()`. It waits for EOF (End-Of-File) to read the content. If you're testing it in a terminal, you can signify EOF by pressing `Ctrl-D` on Linux/macOS or `Ctrl-Z` on Windows.*